# How can I parse a URL in Opal?

Tags: opalrb

Let's say I have a URL that I want to parse, including the query string:

```
https://www.example.com/foo?bar=1&a[]=x&a[]=y
```

I would expect to be able to obtain a hash of the query string like:

```rb
{ "bar" => "1", "a" => ["x", "y"] }
```

**How can I parse this using Opal?**  I looked at options like URI and even CGI from Ruby, but it seems they are unavailable.

Clearly, I could break apart this string myself (or possibly use the Addressable gem), but I would like to use some included library function instead.

Answer (score 1):

hmdne on the Opal Slack has pointed me to `opal-browser` which [includes the `Browser::FormData.parse_query(s)` method](https://github.com/opal/opal-browser/blob/5ce4863b5469cc5139f386292e2e0207cf2074cb/opal/browser/form_data.rb#L124-L126).